# Corrupted data on SSD but tests passed

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystem-corruption

I am trying to find out why I've got corrupted data on a ext4 partition of LUKS encrypted SSD.
I've run `e2fsck /dev/mapper/disk1-root -y`, then `e2fsck -fcc /dev/mapper/disk1-root` with this output:

```
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
/dev/mapper/disk1-root: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/mapper/disk1-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/disk1-root: 139844/3391488 files (3.0% non-contiguous), 4920693/13554688 blocks
```

Then:

```
root@ubuntu:~# smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-18-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     64GB SATA Flash Drive
Serial Number:    B041839840000000106C
LU WWN Device Id: 5 dc663a 04f80106c
Firmware Version: SFDN005E
User Capacity:    64,023,257,088 bytes [64.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      < 1.8 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Mar 13 14:06:33 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (   32) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  24) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2180
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       66
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 30/60)
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       407634110

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1765         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Data corruption is not (necessarily) an indication of a bad drive. A misbehaving program or an improper shutdown may have caused the corruption.

Comment: Is it possible an improper shutdown could corrupt files meant only to read like a config file in /etc?